# Confidence interval for the mean

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, statistical-power, t-distribution, z-score

> If we want to create a confidence interval to estimate the mean of a specific population and we want the margin of error not to exceed $10$ at confidence level of $90\%$ given that some study suggests that the standard deviation of such population is $15$.
>
> What is the smallest sample size?

In this [link](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/confidence-intervals-one-sample/estimating-population-mean/v/sample-size-for-a-given-margin-of-error-for-a-mean?modal=1), they provided that question and an answer which is confusing me.  They said that the interval will be the sample mean $\pm t_n \times \frac{SD}{\sqrt{n}}$; then they substituted $t_n$ by $z$ in order to avoid that $t_n$ requires that we already know the sample size.

But, I have this perspective to use $t_n$ and the answer is different, hence I need a specialist to judge and answer the following approach:

Using the inequality expression that

$$\sqrt{n} \geq 1.5 t_n$$

We need the min $n$ relative to max $t_n$ and also satisfies the above inequality. Using trial and error:

- $n=7$ does not satisfy the inequality.
- $n=8$ does not satisfy.
- But $n=9$ does as follows:
  \begin{align}
  \sqrt{9} &= 3 \ \textrm{and}  \\
  1.5 \times 1.860 &= 2.79  \\
  3 &> 2.79
  \end{align}

Then min sample size for this case is $9$ not $7$ as calculated using $z$.

Comment: The Z distribution is used in case you know the population SD, in case you don't you use the t distribution, which is only approximately normally distributed.

Comment: Welcome to Stats.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](
https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), on [formatting help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: If you don't know the population SD, and only know what the sample SD will be, and if the sample size is large, using $z$ or $t_n$ will give approximate results. However, is the sample size is small, $t_n$ and $z$ may differ, as in the example you presented. In this case, there is no other option than trial and error (since the expression for $t_n$ is not "simple"). My suggestion would be to use $z$ in the first approach and if we get a small sample size, then iteratively use $t_{n(i)}$, where $n(i)$ is the sample size of the previous attempt, until the sample size stabilizes.

Comment: I wonder whether the answers to this question might differ in the following two scenarios: (1) the "some study" was a sample of size two and (2) that study was a sample of a million.  Bear in mind the possibility--indeed, the desirability--of using that study's results when analyzing the new data.